# Xamarin Form Add Multiple Binding

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Please I need help.

I have my Xamarin Form app that works very well with DataBinding to its **View Model** named **OrderDetailViewModel**.

But today I have to add another DataBinding field in line 10 `Binding OrderStatusMessage` that is bind to its Xaml.cs file (code behind) but out of curiosity this field doesn't work I mean it is not changing the Label Text dynamically after binding the label text to a property located in its xaml.cs file (code behind file).

In line 4 you can find the data binding to MVVM file called OrderDetailViewModel which works well.

But the issue is in line 10 `Binding OrderStatusMessage` which is a DataBinding to its own xaml.cs file doesn't change the Label text to new message.
I tested the same code `Binding OrderStatusMessage` outside of the CollectionView.ItemTemplate tag and it's working properly, so only when I put inside CollectionView.ItemTemplate tag that's is not pulling the updated text.

**In the below code there's only one property that is bind to its xaml.cs file (code behind) which is in line 10 `{Binding OrderStatusMessage}` that doesn't get the updated text, the rest are bind to the MVVM which works well.**

PS : I would like to add Multiple Binding to this below code in line 4 :

***filename : OrderDetailViewPage.xaml***

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate >
        <StackLayout
            xct:TouchEffect.LongPressCommand="{Binding LongPressCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:OrderDetailViewModel}}}"
            xct:TouchEffect.LongPressCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
            xct:TouchEffect.PressedScale="1.2"
            xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True">

            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding OrderStatusMessage}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="fasolid" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <Label Text="{Binding Id}"
                FontSize="Medium"/>
            <Label Text="Order number" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding OrderId}"
                TextColor="Purple" FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding OrderDetail}"
                TextColor="Purple"
                FontSize="Small" />
            <Label Text="{Binding OrderDate}"
                TextColor="Purple"
                FontSize="Small" />
            <Label Text="{Binding IsOrderComplete}"
                TextColor="Purple"
                FontSize="Small" />
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant VM code

Comment: @Jason Thank you so much for trying to help me out. The problem is not in VM, all the field bind to MVVM works well. There's only one field that is binding to its own xaml.cs file (code behind) which is `<Label Text="{Binding OrderStatusMessage}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="fasolid" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
                                    </StackLayout>`  which doesn't get updated.

Comment: @Jason But when I move this code out of **CollectionView.ItemTemplate** block its works well, it gets the updated message.  **I read somewhere that I need multiple binding.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried bind your Label inside CollectionView.ItemTemplate using Path property?
Like this : `<Label Text = "{Binding Path=OrderStatusMessage, Source = {x:Reference pageName}}"/>`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried your code and I got the below error message : **Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException
  Message=Position 67:44. Can not find the object referenced by `OrderDetailViewPage`
  Source=Xamarin.Forms.Xaml**

Comment: Did you use x:Name from your content page as a reference?

Comment: Should x:Reference pageName  be the real page name? if so, I did it, I changed pageName to the real page name **OrderDetailViewPage** like below `Source = {x:Reference OrderDetailViewPage}}`

Comment: pageName can be any name, this is how it is declared
`<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                         .....
                         x:Name="pageName">
`

Comment: No, I didn't set any x:Name for content page.

Comment: Try it, it works on my code

Comment: Thank you so so much. Now it's working fine, you fixed my issue. Can you please suggest me what book to read to improve my Xamarin.Form skills ?

Comment: Glad I helped, unfortunately I have no advice for the book other than that for me the best way to learn Xamarin.Forms is to practice and read the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/)

Comment: Thank so much for your advice. But how do I need to practice?  Do I need to practice chapter after chapter after reading or create kind of a side project ?  **What is the best way to practice according to you?**